# Circuit analysis with 2 diodes : Constant Voltage model

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

It's a problem about sketching V_in  V_out characteristics(sketching graph with V_in as x axis, V_out as y axis) with constant voltage model in different V_D,on (V_D1,on != V_D2, on)

Starting from V_in = -inf, both D1 and D2 are turned off : (D1, D2) = (off, off) and it's obvious that V_out = V_in until one(or both) of diodes will turn on.

After that, I have to find the condition for one of diode turning on : like (on, off), or (off, on).

But how can I know which of 2 diodes will turn on first as V_in increases from -inf?

Both (on, off) and (off, on) are reasonable I think... I can't decide what's collect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *But how can I know which of 2 diodes will turn on first as V_in
> increases from -inf?*

Well there are tools that can help such as a simulator but I guess you might not be that keen on simulation so, ask yourself, what maximum positive voltage can be at the input that doesn't cause current to flow through D1. No current in D1 means you can analyse stuff without it affecting the math.

I say a positive voltage because clearly D1 is reverse biased by \$V_B\$ so, to make it conduct, D2 and R2 must be acting as a partial clamp on the output so that there is a volt drop across R1.... But there's the answer, D2 has to be conducting before D1.

Alternatively you could look at the problem without the presence of D1 and, in your minds-eye, raise the input voltage and tabulate what the voltage is across the nodes of the missing D1 diode. At some point it will become forward biased and, at that point that is the voltage needed at the input to get to the onset of D1 conduction.

But, in short, D2 will be conducting before D1.

Comment: Don’t short that D2. Ha

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 don't try to be so clever Tony LOL

Comment: Some try, I do....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Vf of the diode is neglected when On for simplicity since the type is unspecified, the solution is logical and simple.

￼

- For 0< Vin< Vb.

  - R1 and R2 conduct as a simple voltage divider **Vout/Vin=R2/(R1+R2)**
    until Vin=Vb.
  - when Vin>Vb the battery and R(D1)+R(Vb) values are low (0) which shunts R1 then.
  - **Vout=Vin-Vb** and R2 may reduce not attenuate this impedance.

.

- for Vin<0     Both D1,D2 are open so only R1 conducts and **Vout/Vin=1**

￼

Comment: So you mean, I can use ideal diode model first to predict the behavior(which one is turning on/off), then use the constant-voltage model, right?

Comment: You got it.....0.65V @ 1mA for all silicon diodes is accurate (enuf) while 0.7 may not due to size and Rs signal vs power diodes gives the right ballpark answer that makes easy sense, the 2nd improves accuracy...(I hate IosIpad auto correct sometimes)

Comment: But since diodes can conduct at very low currents easily at half the voltage, Andy is correct that D2 conducts with R1 before Vb is reached to start D1, but R ratios are TBD. if R2>>R1 the difference is inconsequential